# In Perforce, can you rename a folder to the same name but cased differently?

Tags: windows, perforce

Can I rename a folder in Perforce from *//depot/FooBar/* to *//depot/Foobar/*?

I've tried this by renaming from *//depot/FooBar/* to *//depot/Temp/* to *//Depot/Foobar/* but the end result ends up the same as *//depot/FooBar/*.

Answer (score 11):

Once it is in Perforce, the case remains set. As mentioned by Johan you can obliterate, set the name up correctly, and add it in again. However, there is a slight gotcha....

If anyone else (running Windows) has already synced the wrong-cased version, then when they sync again the right one, it will not change the case on their PC. This is a peculiarity of the Windows file system acknowledging case but still being fundamentally case-independent.

If a number of users have synced, and it is not convenient to get them to remove-from-client too (and blasting the folders from their machines), then you can resort to a dark and dirty Perforce technique called "Checkpoint surgery". It's not for the fainthearted, but you do this:

1. Stop your server, take a checkpoint.
2. Using your favourite text editor that can handle multi-megabyte files, search & replace all occurances of the old case name with the new. You could of course use a script too.
3. Replay your checkpoint file to recreate the Perforce database meta data.
4. Restart your server.

This will affect all user client specs transparently, and so when they sync they will get the right case as if by magic.

It sounds hairy, but I've had to do it before and as long as you take care, backup, do a trial run etc, then all should be OK.

Comment: Windows doesn't really care about filename case, but *remembers* it. One of my co-workers refers to this as "case-retentive". :-)

Comment: I think the case-remembering may happen no matter what your platform.  I know I've had that happen on Linux before, to my eventual chagrin when I tracked down the problem.  I think perforce itself does a case-insensitive check for the path.

Comment: Would someone please add a comment defining "obliterate" in this context? Do you simply mean using the OS to delete the file from the drive?

Comment: @Craig - "Obliterate" in this context is a reference to the Perforce command "p4 obliterate" which removes all reference to a file in Perforce as if it had never existed. As opposed to "p4 delete" that still keeps the file around complete with its history.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe not needed anymore, but here's the official Perforce HowTo about changing file cases on Windows and Unix: http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3448/?q=change+file+case

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about directories, but we've had this problem with files. To fix it, we have to delete the file, submit that change, then p4 add the file with the correct case and submit the second change. Once that's done, unix users who have sync'ed the incorrect-case file have to p4 sync, then physically delete the file (because p4 won't update the case) and then p4 sync -f the file.

Our server is on Windows, so that might make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it treats files and folders the same.

For files:
It depends (on whether you have a Windows or Unix server).  We have this problem with our Windows perforce server (which versions our Java code), where very occasionally someone will check in a file with a case problem (this then causes compile errors because it's Java).  The only way to fix this is to obliterate the file and resubmit it with the correct case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove the Perforce Cache, so that your modification can be shown.

You can rename with ABC rename to abc_TMP, then abc_TMP rename to abc, then clear cache.

Setps to clear cache:

1. Open windows user home folder (on windows7 ==> C:\Users\)
2. Locate the folder called ".p4qt"
3. Rename the folder to "old.p4qt"
4. Launch Perforce, now everything works!

NOTE: these steps will rest your default setting.

Answer (score 0):

The question is over 3 years old, but I ran into an issue like this while doing a Subversion import into Perforce and figured the info I got could be useful to some. It's similar to the obliterate method, but helps you retain history. You use the duplicate command that may not have been available back then to retain the history. The process basically being:

1. Duplicate to temporary location.
2. Obliterate the location you just duplicated.
3. Duplicate from the temporary location to the renamed case location.
4. Obliterate the temporary location.

Through this you retain the history of file changes, but get them all in the new path as well. Unfortunately there will be no history of the path case change, but that seems to be unavoidable. Similar to other methods mentioned here, users will need to either manually rename the directories in their workspace or delete and re-sync to get the new path name.

Also, P4V caches the paths it shows in the tree so after doing this it may still show up as the old name. a p4 dirs command however will show the new case.